# XSD 1.1 Assert to Count and Compare Elements

Tags: xsd, assert

I currently have an XSD file which controls the validation etc towards my corresponding XML file, and I would like to control (preferably using an assert command rather than XLST [as I have no prior knowledge of this]) and be able to ensure there are the same number of abc:Country tags to abc:AccountNumber tags, as one should correspond to the other

```
    <abc:Account>
      <abc:Individual>
        <abc:Country>Germany</abc:Country>
        <abc:Country>Australia</abc:Country>
        <abs:AccountNumber issuedBy="DE">123456</abs:AccountNumber>
        <abs:AccountNumber issuedBy="AU">654321</abs:AccountNumber>
      </abc:Individual>
    </abc:Account>
```

Please can someone help me out with the assert command I can use perform this validation?

I have tried the following to no avail...

```
    <xsd:assert test="if (count (abc:Account/abc:Individual/abc:Country) eq (count (abc:Account/abc:Individual/AccountNumber))) then true() else false() "/>
```

or this....

```
    <xsd:assert test="count (abc:Account/abc:Individual/abc:Country) eq count (abc:Account/abc:Individual/AccountNumber)"/>
```

I presume this is doable using XSD 1.1?

any help will be greatly appreciated.... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes most sense to have the assert in the type definition for the `abc:Individual` element, then the assert is simply:

```
count(abc:Country) eq count(abc:AccountNumber)
```

The complete schema is like so. For simplicity I kept `AccountNumber` in the `abc` namespace, but it can be easily replaced with a reference otherwise.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:abc="http://www.example.com/abc"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/abc"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="Account">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="abc:Individual" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Individual">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="abc:Country" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element ref="abc:AccountNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="count(abc:Country) eq count(abc:AccountNumber)"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="AccountNumber">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="issuedBy" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Apart from changing `abs` to `abc`, the original document validates successfully against the schema, i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc:Account
    xmlns:abc="http://www.example.com/abc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/abc test.xsd">
    <abc:Individual>
        <abc:Country>Germany</abc:Country>
        <abc:Country>Australia</abc:Country>
        <abc:AccountNumber issuedBy="DE">123456</abc:AccountNumber>
        <abc:AccountNumber issuedBy="AU">654321</abc:AccountNumber>
    </abc:Individual>
</abc:Account>
```

Comment: Ghislain Fourny thank you ever so much! Quick and concise respond, worked just as I wanted it! Thank you!!! :)